# How to call the id value from one page to another page

Tags: php, html

I just want to call the id value of one page in another page, but it has not been working for me for a long time. I have given the id value to the form as "addedcart" and called in php code but it is not displaying any cart value. Is it correct to call an id like this? Because I don't know perfectly about php. The form which I want to be called is given below:

```
<?php
  $addedcart = $_POST['addedcart'];
  $formcontent="Items in cart: $addedcart";
  mail($recipient,$subject,$formcantent,$headers) or die("Error!");
?> 
<form action="" method="post" class="last" id="addedcart">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="info@domain.com" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
    <input type="hidden" name="display" value="1" />
    <input type="image" name="submit" src="images/cart.png" class="button"/>
 </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the limited information we have, I can see two possible solutions:

**Solution 1: $_SESSION variable**

Start your PHP code with `session_start();` and make `$_SESSION['addedcart']` equal to what you want. This will carry over to any page that uses `session_start();` and can't be changed by the end-user.

**Solution 2: Hidden Form Input**

Add the following to the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="addedcart" value="<?php echo $addedcart ?>" />
```

The downside of this method is that a user can change these values in the Developer tools in Chrome/Firefox.